# Disable all startup Items

Tags: windows-8

With Windows 7, when I come across a slow computer one of the first setting I change is Startup Items. I go to

```
msconfig
```

<kbd>Startup</kbd> tab

Then click <kbd>Disable all</kbd>

However, now on Windows 8 these programs are now in the Startup tab of the Task Manager, with no apparent way to disable all startup programs. Can these all be disabled at once?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to just disable all startup items. While most are usually useless, some may be required for system to work correctly (like ATK on Asus laptops).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

```
autoruns -e
```

[image: autoruns Sysinternals Suite]

Comment: So I have to download a 12 MB file to **get back** the functionality that was in Windows 7? Wow.

Comment: @StevenPenny Slightly larger described here list http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027 )

Comment: @StevenPenny: Autoruns GUI and command-line versions combined clock in at half an MB or so - is that too big for you for such brilliant apps?